# How wait to AJAX response

Tags: ajax

i wanna know how i can make a pause in the system to wait the answer from the server in an AJAX request?

```
var method = childs[cont].getAttribute('method');
            var address = childs[cont].getAttribute('address');
            /*
             * Making the AJAX connection 
             * and returning the results.
             */
            phone = new ConstructorXMLHttpRequest();
            onreadystatechange = function(){
                switch(phone.readyState){
                    case 0: if(phone.readyState == 0){
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1: if(phone.readyState == 1){
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: if(phone.readyState == 2){
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3: if(phone.readyState == 3){
                        break;
                    }
                    case 4: if(phone.readyState == 4){
                        if(phone.status == 200){
                            var val = phone.responseText; 
                            alert([val,1]);
                            dataInsert(val);
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Problemas status:"+phone.status+" state:"+phone.readyState);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            phone.onreadystatechange = onreadystatechange;
            if (method == 'POST'){
                phone.open(method, address, true);
                phone.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
                phone.send(xml2string(prepCall(childs[cont])));
            }else if(method == 'GET'){
                phone.open(method, address, true);
                phone.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks OK. Remember AJAX is asynchronous, so instead of actually pausing, just hook a callback to your ajax request which will be executed once the request is completed.

In your case, if the request is completed successfully it will alert and execute the dateInsert function.

Comment: Thanks i solved the problem i make sometimes async and sometimes not.